# Проблема со стилем

Tags: javascript

Не могу получить стиль элемента

```
       <div id="sam">
             <div class="cat"></div>
             <div class="cat"></div>
             <div class="cat"></div>
             <div class="cat"></div>
       </div>

    var strChild = sam.childNodes[0]
    if(strChild.style.color == '') // True
```

в сss прописано color: black;

Comment: style - это то, что непосредственно указано в style аттрибуте

Comment: а почему тогда alert(strChild.style) == [object CSSStyleDeclaration], ключевое слово CSS

И как тогда получить доступ именно к CSS

А если через jQuery делать, то он находит?

Comment: Расковыряйте jQuery и посмотрите, как это сделано там. Тогда это не будет казаться бредом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо обращаться к свойству `currentStyle` (IE) или вызывать метод `getComputedStyle`.